# The right way to create an array with N range?

Tags: javascript, arrays, numbers, range

I want to create an array with numbers from `1` to **`n`**. For example if my **`n`** number is `8` I need my `list` array to be:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

Of course it could be done with `for` loop, like so:

```
var n = 8;
var list = [];
for(var i=1;i!=n+1;i++){
    list.push(i);
}
```

But is there some unique way to do this?

I have also tried `new Array(8)` but it didn't do what it need:

```
[ , , , , , , , ]
```

Comment: I guess, a loop is the only way - but if you're willing to use libraries for this, take a look at [lodash's range function](http://lodash.com/docs#range).

Comment: There is no more elegant way to do it than the array. Unless you know the elements from the beginingm, then you can use var arr=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

Comment: https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/2.4.1/dist/lodash.compat.js#L5067

Comment: `(new Array(9)).join('x').split('').map(function(_, i) { return i+1; });`

Comment: Take a looks at duplicated post, there are probably all possible ways.